# Rails link_to path variable convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, nested-routes

Sorry, this is a naive question.

I have a nested resources depth 2 levels.

```
  resources :programs do  
    resources :questions do
      resources :answers
    end
  end
```

So for the index,edit, etc pages to work I need to modify the `link_to` attribute for `show`, `edit`, `new` buttons in the views.

For eg,

<%= link_to 'Show', edit_question_path %>

How should I rename this `edit_question_path` to? Should it be `edit_question_program_path` or it should be `edit_program_question_path`. I am confused of this convention, if we have programs->questions-> answers, then how should the convention be in the `link_to`'s path?. Please help

Answer (score 1):

To know which route to use, just fire `rake routes` to see the right path name.

Also, in this case you need to supply three objects for `link_to`

```
link_to "Something", 
  edit_program_question_answer_path(@program, @question, @answer)
```

Isn't that ugly? Lots of works to do to feed link_to alone, and there will be more.

Don't abuse nested resources. Never use them over 2 in my opinion. I myself prefer to avoid nested resource at all when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so how should I redesign my models,routes in order to make them less cumbersome?

Comment: @Clone, this does nothing with models, just the routes. You can give each model a separate resource when nested resource is not a must. You can check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more.